# Unity: Interrupting Animations

Tags: unity, animation

When I interrupt an Animator Controller during an Animation and reopen it the Armature gets stuck (more or less) at the point where the previous Animation was interrupted. How can I safely and instantly quit an animation without destroying it?

Please watch the Video to fully comprehend the problem: https://youtu.be/O9X5SBATHRw

Screenshot of Problem:

[image]

Screenshot of Animator Controller:

[image]

Part of the Weapon Switch Script:

```
disableWeaponModel(weaponNameList[activeWeapon]); //Disable active Weapon Model

if (holsteredWeapon == -1) //If player carries only 1 weapon
    holsteredWeapon = activeWeapon; //Active Weapon is holstered
else //Player already carries 2 weapons
    actionDropGun(); //Active Weapon is thrown (New LOD generated)

activeWeapon = getWeaponIDfromLOD(targetName); //Active Weapon is set to Target LOD

setWeaponVars(activeWeapon); //Set all variables to the active Weapon
setWeaponModel(weaponNameList[activeWeapon]); //Set Weapon Model to the active Weapon
setAnimator(weaponNameList[activeWeapon]); //Set Animations to the active Weapon
```

setAnimator(string name) Function from above (last code line):

```
void setAnimator(string name)
{
    //Add new guns here
    if (name == "MP5A3")
        currentWeaponAnimation = MP5A3_Animation;
    else if (name == "Rpk-74")
        currentWeaponAnimation = Rpk74_Animation;
    else if (name == "Skorpion")
        currentWeaponAnimation = Skorpion_Animation;
}
```

Variables from setAnimator(string name):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning on **Optimize Game Objects** on the Rig tab of your model fixed this for me (Generic/Humanoid animations only). The only problem is that it won't work for you, if you actually need the model bones as gameobjects.